# Python error while coding in Swift: unexpected indent (Xcode 11)

Tags: python, swift, xcode

Edit:
For those who want actual code, please consult this link for all related source code.
https://github.com/objcio/S01E118-introduction-prototype

Why am I getting the following error:

> error: module importing failed: unexpected indent
>   (sniff_objc_exception_throw.py, line 7)   File "temp.py", line 1, in

I am using a project example from SwiftTalk which doesn't have any obvious python code anywhere, which makes me think this might be an Xcode import issue.  Has anyone seen this? Is there something I can do to solve the issue?

[image]

The project code uses an older version of Swift (which matt points out below...).  Here is my code after updating to remove all compile errors and running the Convert/Update to Swift 5 Utility:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func setSubviews<S: Sequence>(_ other: S) where S.Element == UIView {
        let views = Set(other)
        let sub = Set(subviews)
        for v in sub.subtracting(views) {
            v.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        for v in views.subtracting(sub) {
            addSubview(v)
        }
    }
}


extension UILabel {
    convenience init(text: String, size: UIFont.TextStyle, multiline: Bool = false) {
        self.init()
        font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: size)
        self.text = text
        adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        if multiline {
            numberOfLines = 0
        }
    }
}

indirect enum Layout {
    case view(UIView, Layout)
    case newline(Layout)
    case choice(Layout, Layout)
    case empty
}

extension Layout {
    func apply(containerWidth: CGFloat) -> [UIView] {
        var result: [UIView] = []
        var origin: CGPoint = .zero
        var current: Layout = self
        var lineHeight: CGFloat = 0
        while true {
        switch current {
            case let .view(v, rest):
                result.append(v)
                let availableWidth = containerWidth - origin.x
                let size = v.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: availableWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
                v.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
                lineHeight = max(lineHeight, size.height)
                origin.x += size.width
                current = rest
            case let .newline(rest):
                origin.x = 0
                origin.y += lineHeight
                lineHeight = 0
                current = rest
            case let .choice(first, second):
                if first.fits(currentX: origin.x, containerWidth: containerWidth) {
                    current = first
                } else {
                    current = second
                }
            case .empty:
                return result
            }
        }
    }

    func fits(currentX: CGFloat, containerWidth: CGFloat) -> Bool {
        var x = currentX
        var current: Layout = self
        while true {
            switch current {
            case let .view(v, rest):
                let availableWidth = containerWidth - x
                let size = v.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: availableWidth, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
                x += size.width
                if x >= containerWidth { return false }
                current = rest
            case let .newline(rest):
                x = 0
                current = rest
            case let .choice(first, second):
                if first.fits(currentX: x, containerWidth: containerWidth) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    current = second
                }
            case .empty:
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}

final class LayoutContainer: UIView {
    let layout: Layout
    init(_ layout: Layout) {
        self.layout = layout
        super.init(frame: .zero)

//        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setNeedsLayout), name: Notification.Name.UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let views = layout.apply(containerWidth: bounds.width)
        setSubviews(views)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let titleLabel = UILabel(text: "Building a Layout Library", size: .headline, multiline: true)
        let episodeNumber = UILabel(text: "Episode 123", size: .body)
        let episodeDate = UILabel(text: "September 23", size: .body)

        let horizontal = Layout.view(episodeNumber, Layout.view(episodeDate, .empty))
        let vertical = Layout.view(episodeNumber, .newline(Layout.view(episodeDate, .empty)))
        let layout = Layout.view(titleLabel, .newline(
            .choice(horizontal, vertical)
            ))

        let container = LayoutContainer(layout)
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(container)
        view.addConstraints([
            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
        ])

    }
}
```

To be clear: if you copy and paste this code over the project's existing ViewController.swift content, the project compiles, then runs with only the indicated error (module importing failed:....)

Comment: Post code as text and not as an image

Comment: none of the code posted as an image is relevant to the question. As the question states, there are no obvious references to python anywhere in the project (that I can see).

Comment: I assume you didn't mean to link to `http://SwiftProject`, so I went ahead and changed it to the github link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finally able to answer this because Xcode 12 Beta 2 printed out a path for the offending file.
I'm not sure where the file came from... although I remember installing Swiftify -- that's the only extension I ever remember installing.  Perhaps when I removed Swiftify it was left behind?

My solution was to find the file at the indicated path and remove it.

Using Finder I navigated to
~/Library/lldb
and deleted the file:

> sniff_objc_exception_throw.py

Answer (score 1):

The heart of the problem is a Swift language version issue. The project you're referring to is so old that it can't be compiled in modern-day Swift. This generates all sorts of secondary issues as the layout manager chokes because it can't parse the code. The solution is to update the code to match the version of Swift in your compiler.

In particular, change `UIFontTextStyle` to `UIFont.TextStyle` and change `Notification.Name.UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange` to `UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification`.

Comment: Thanks, matt.  I agree with your assessment. I have already done what you've suggested, and still have an error.  I am in the middle of refactoring, and will retrace my steps.  I'll update the question with current code (which compiles with no other errors), and remove my refactorings until the error disappears. I won't be able to do this for a few hours, though.

Comment: Hi matt.  I redownloaded, fixed all compiler-signaled issues, then ran the convert to Swift 5 utility. The error remains.

Comment: All I can tell you is that I downloaded the linked project, made the changes I described, and compiled and ran in Xcode 11.1, no problem. If you're doing something different, you have not said what it is, so I can't help further.

Comment: Ok. When I get home I’ll download 11.1 and accept your answer. Many thanks.

Comment: Well don't accept it unless it works! If there's something else going on, we need to try to figure out what it is. The problem is that I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I downloaded the 11.1 GM release, installed, rebooted, cleaned the project and rebuilt. Same error.  Very puzzled you don't get the same results.

Comment: Have you modified Xcode in any way? Some sort of editor extension? Swift lint? Anything like that? - Oh, here's something to try! Make a new User and log into the new User. Now try it. If it works, then yes, you made some modification to Xcode in the old User.